# Scrolling jumps when clicking jqGrid cell

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have a jqGrid setup that is rather wide, so it the horizontal scrollbar is visible.

Problem is, when scrolling to the right and clicking on a cell, the scrollbar jumps all the way back to the left.

Any ideas why this is happening and how I can prevent it?

Comment: Are you using anchor tags with `href="#"`?

Comment: No. Some of the cells are editable, some are just text.

Comment: The last thing to check would be that "#" isn't appearing in the location bar. If that isn't the case, is jqGrid re-drawing when you click on a cell? (possibly causing the horizontal scrollbar to go away for a millisecond, resulting in a jump)

Comment: @KevinB No # in the location bar, and the grid is not redrawing when clicking on a cell

Comment: Look at it this way, there's only 3 things that will make the page scroll (not including the user doing it); Hash change, page width/height change, and the code doing it directly.

Comment: @KevinB It's not actually the whole page that scrolls, it's the div that the grid is in

Comment: right, but those elements follow the same rules.

Comment: @KevinB yeah, I'd guessed it was code, but jqGrid is so complex I can't figure out where this is happening

Comment: Did you find a solution ? I am actually having the same issue

Comment: I am seeing the same issue. Only when cellEdit is turned on for the grid. I don't know of a solution yet.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue with jqGrid4.1.2
After tried so many ways, I found the solution

After making the grid, please do the following things:

1. Call GridNav function of jqGrid
   `jQuery('#id').jqGrid('GridNav');`
2. Then add postion of gridId_kn element's parent attribute : `position:fixed`
   set if position is not added already
   `jQuery('#id_kn').parent().attr("style", style+"position:fixed");`